# Database design for simple money transfers and normalization

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Let's say I have typical application where user can transfer some virtual money. So I will probably have something like

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  balance money NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
CREATE TABLE transfers(
  user_from integer NOT NULL REFERENCES users (id),
  user_to integer NOT NULL REFERENCES users (id),
  amount money NOT NULL
);
```

Then I just will add `AFTER INSERT` trigger to `transfers` table, so it will update `balance` on each transfer.

But is it the best solution these days? Can it be done better with views or something else? I'm really feel like it's not the case when I should have unnormalized data.

P.S. I'm using PostgreSQL if it matters.

Thanks.

Comment: Your `transfers` table lacks a primary key. Besides that, what unnormalized data are you referring to?

Comment: balance can be calculated from summation of amounts from transfers table. So I'm thinking about the view which calculates it and cache somehow, this cache should be flush for separated row on transfers update.

Comment: Normalization doesn't address aggregated data, your `users` table doesn't violate any normal form.

Comment: But still. Can I somehow achieve the result with view and caching? And will it be better in any way?

Comment: How will you handle opening balances?

Comment: E.g. with records with `user_from` set to `NULL`

Comment: Whether a view would be better is debatable.  Allowing nulls in your transfers table can affect the validity of your data. You can see the balance column as a simple cache, provided you can keep it valid, it comes down to the complexity and performance of views vs triggers. Triggers can do additional work, e.g. check if a user has enough funds, for which the balance column would be convenient. You could combine triggers with views to do the same without a balance column. Personally, I think a balance column plus triggers allows for a simple effective design.

Comment: Ok, i see, thank you. I think you should put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalization doesn't address aggregated data, your users table doesn't violate any normal form.

Whether a view would be better is debatable. Allowing nulls in your transfers table can affect the validity of your data. You can see the balance column as a simple cache, provided you can keep it valid, it comes down to the complexity and performance of views vs triggers. Triggers can do additional work, e.g. check if a user has enough funds, for which the balance column would be convenient. You could combine triggers with views to do the same without a balance column. Personally, I think a balance column plus triggers allows for a simple effective design.